# Где в реестре расположен GUID иконки из области уведомлений windows 7?

Tags: windows, реестр

В Windows 7 иконки из области уведомлений (notify icons) привязываются при первом вызове

```
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);
```

к пути исполняемого файла. Поэтому при вызове в приложении функции `Shell_NotifyIcon` с тем же GUID иконки (само приложение теперь перемещено в другую папку) иконка не появляется. Как удалить из реестра GUID этой иконки при деинсталяции приложения и где этот GUID в реестре расположен?

Comment: Поищите гуид поиском?)

Answer (score 2):

Информация об иконках в трее хранится в ветке реестра `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify`, в бинарном ключе IconStreams, который не документирован.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете поискать нужные Вам {GUID} в разделе реестра `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`

Comment: Это я уже пробовал,самое странное что его там нет,хотя там должны быть все GUIDы.Видимо microsoft решили засандалить его в какой-нибудь другой раздел,хотя я пользовался поиском по всему реестру и так ничего и не нашел

Comment: Попробуйте как то оригинально назвать ваш ехе (или путь до него), создать иконку в области уведомлений и после создания и привязки найти в реестре по пути/имени